# How to add a word to the left side of the ubuntu terminal?

Tags: terminal, customization

When activating a python virtualenv the name of the environment appears of the left side of the command line.

```
(venv) something@SOMETHING:~
```

how can i do this with a custom word?

Example

```
(cheese) something@SOMETHING:~
```

**EDIT**

I dont want a virtualenv named cheese! i would like the equivalent terminal command that adds a word.

Comment: when you activate your environment, the shell variable `PS1` is modified. You can modify that variable in order to display what you wish.

Comment: Or, you could just name the virtual environment "cheese".

Comment: What is the command that adds a name to the left terminal... i know how to name virtual envs

Comment: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/COMMANDS.md

Comment: `PS1` replaces all the line with the word though. and the colors go white.

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html